# Continuation map interpolating two quadratic Hamiltonians with respect to different contact boundaries

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, symplectic-topology, floer-homology, fukaya-category, pseudo-holomorphic-curves

Let $(M,\lambda)$ be a Liouville manifold. Consider two different contact boundaries $\partial_{\infty}^1M$ and $\partial_{\infty}^2M$ with respect to the same Liouville flow $Z$. Each of them determines a class ${\cal H}_i(M),~i=1,2$ of Hamiltonians which are quadratic at infinity.

Given an admissible Lagrangian $L$ for wrapped Floer theory (i.e. exact, $\lambda|_L\equiv 0$ at infinity and satisfying a non-degeneracy condition for both $\partial_{\infty}^1M$ and $\partial_{\infty}^2M$). We have well-defined wrapped Floer cochain complexes
$CW^*(L,L;H_i,J_i),~i=1,2$ for generic Floer data $(H_i,J_i)$ with $H_i\in {\cal H}_i(M)$.

Is there a well-defined continuation map
$$CW^*(L,L;H_1,J_1)\rightarrow CW^*(L,L;H_2,J_2)?$$

Comment: The short answer is yes, at least for contact type almost complex structures. First you rescale to get $H_2 > H_1$ near infinity and interpolate with $H_s$. Then you prove that for $u$ a disk contributing to the continuation map, $H_s\circ u$ satisfies a maximum principle.